# if $|G|=q^3$ then for all $y \in G$ we have $y^3 \in Z(G)$ where $q$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to know that either this statement is false or true.
This is obvious for when $G$ is commutative.

Suppose that $G$ is noncommutative.

I started with the fact that when $|G|=q^3$ then $|Z(G)|=q$. (where $Z(G)$ is the center of G)

My idea is to show that $y^3Z(G)=Z(G)$ for all $y \in G$ but I do not know how to continue.

Can anyone also show that this is true when $q=3$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can take $q=2$, consider the quaternions.

Comment: It's not true when $q \ne 3$, but for $q \ne 3$ you need to replace $y^3 \in Z(G)$ by $y^q \in Z(G)$. Then it's true for all prime $q$. Note that $|G/Z(G)| = q^2$, and $G/Z(G)$ cannot be cyclic.